# Performance of using OpenGL UBOs for camera matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, pipeline

I've read about how to use UBOs in OpenGL from [this](http://opengl.datenwolf.net/gltut/html/Positioning/Tut07%20Shared%20Uniforms.html) tutorial, in which it is suggested that both the projection and camera position matrix be stored in a single UBO, shared between shaders, like this:

```
layout(std140) uniform global_transforms
{
    mat4 camera_orientation;
    mat4 camera_projection;
};
```

But it seems to me to make more sense to store the *product* of the camera projection * position matrix multiplication in the UBO, so that the matrix multiplication doesn't have to occur once for every call to the vertex buffer. You'd be sending the same amount of data to the buffer each step, but trading potentially many matrix multiplications on the GPU for just one on the CPU.

My question: am I right in thinking that this would be even just a wee bit more performant? Perhaps the shader compiler is smart enough to perform operations involving only uniforms once per draw?

(I'd just test it myself with a few thousand polygons, but it's my first time working with a programmable pipeline and I haven't quite gotten UBOs working yet :P)

Comment: Some mobile GPU used to do that, generate a special shader run only once, before everything else, that did every uniform only calculations. But I don't know if it's the case anymore. I never saw that happen on PC but maybe some constructors do it too. I'd love to hear someone with more info. Anyway, in general it's a good idea to precompute this kind of things on the CPU and only upload what's needed by the shader. However one matrix multiplication per vertex is a very small difference, you may have trouble measuring an actual gain.

Comment: Almost all my shaders use a pre-multiplied world-view-proj matrix uniform to avoid doing unnecessary transforms in every vertex shader invocation. As the world matrix changes so often between objects, I've never seen any benefit in having a common UBO at all and I tend to use custom uniform buffers all the way.